# Install Packer.nvim problems

Tags: plugins, lua, neovim

I intalled Packer.nvim as in the instructions in the repository, after doing all the plugin configuration, when I go to run the :PackerInstall command NeoVim doesn't recognize it. I checked the Windows Path and apparently everything is fine.

Windows 11 Home
NeaoVim 0.8.1

I try install a Packer.nvim.

Comment: Did you add `require('packer').startup(...)` in your config file?

Comment: Provide your minimal config to reproduce the issue or post a link to your config. Otherwise, how would you suppose other people to help you?

Comment: For those who *nix, try [this](https://www.chiarulli.me/Neovim-2/03-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [README's](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim#requirements) **Requirements**:

> If you are on Windows 10, you need developer mode enabled in order to use local plugins (creating symbolic links requires admin privileges on Windows - credit to @TimUntersberger for this note)

I **git blamed** the **README** and figured that the quoted requirement was written **2 years ago**.
So, I *think* the same *might* still apply on Windows 11. Worth a try (I didn't , cause I can't since I'm on Fedora rn).

Answer (score 0):

This comment is about providing more information about the comment made by @thetrotfreak.

TL;DR: This issue is resolved and admin privileges shouldn't be an issue that Packer is failing.

Here's the update: [Installation of local plugins on Windows requires running with Admin privileges #679](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim/issues/679)